# How do I solve 'str object does not support item assignment'?

Tags: python

I am trying to change some pseudocode into Python and I came across an error.

The pseudocode is:

```
FOR Count - 1 to 13 DO
 OUTPUT "Please enter next digit of ISBN:"
 INPUT ISBN[Count]
```

My Python code is:

```
for Count in range (1,13):
  ISBN[Count] = int(input('Next ISBN digit:'))
```

I then get this errror:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Evidently `ISBN` is a string, so stop trying to assign to it...

Comment: Before attempting to translate to a language you don't have experience with, try researching it a bit.

Comment: thanks for the amazing help guys! @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the array first and use `.append` to add new values to it.

The following example shows how.

```
ISBN=[];
for Count in range (1,3):
  ISBN.append( int(input('Next ISBN digit:')) )

for i in range(0,len(ISBN)):
        print ISBN[i]
```

If you run it with inputs 11 12 you get them printed back on screen.

Comment: Of course you would never do `for i in range(0,len(ISBN)): print ISBN[i]` but `for value in ISBN: print value`.

Comment: Never is too strong a word. It would be more informative if you qualify it. But in any case, that was to show him how to use ```array[i]``` as opposed to his try. His code didn't require printing ISBN.